# what's the difference beteween these proxy_pass example?

Tags: nginx, proxypass

what's the difference beteween these proxy_pass example?

```
location /proxyApi/ {                                         
    proxy_pass http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/;                                     
}  
location /proxyApi {                                         
    proxy_pass http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx;                                     
}  
location /proxyApi/ {                                         
    proxy_pass http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx;                                     
}  
location /proxyApi {                                         
    proxy_pass http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/;                                     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the 1st and 4th example, you have provided an optional URI to the end of the `proxy_pass` statement. This causes the `proxy_pass` to change the URI in a similar way to the `alias` directive by a direct substitution of the text in the `location` statement. Caveats are that the URI has not already been changed within the location block (e.g. with a `rewrite...break`), and that the `location` is a prefix location (as in your question) and the `proxy_pass` contains no variables (as in your question).

The URI `/proxyApi/foo/bar` will pass upstream to `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/foo/bar` in case 1, and `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx//foo/bar` in case 4. *Notice the error with the double `//` in case 4.*

Cases 2 and 3 simply pass the URI upstream without modification. Both pass the URI `/proxyApi/foo/bar` to `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/proxyApi/foo/bar`.

The other difference is URIs such as `/proxyApi` and `/proxyApifoo`, which will only match the `location` blocks in case 2 and 4.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.